# Start Service in Android and communicate with it from multiple Activities

Tags: android, service

Well I would like to communicate to a Service from multiple Activities, like everyone listen to a broadcast channel and update their Twitter statuses ..

My recent effort is to use Broadcast Receiver on each Activity to receive the broadcast sent from the Service. But I would like to know that it's a good way or not and what is the property way?

Furthermore, I would like to ask if i should use Binder to start this kind of service or use startService method (I am a beginner in using Service actually..).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
        OKay you are a beginner in Service means Refer this below Link
```

### http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

```
        in your Question while you using service you must register in Manifest file..
        like this..

        for example i did unlock screen using service and broadcast receiver.

        <service
                    android:name="com.services.Unlock_Service"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
                </service>

        unlockservice.java



        package com.services;

        import java.util.List;

        import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ActivityManager;
        import android.app.KeyguardManager;
        import android.app.Service;
        import android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock;
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.ComponentName;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.IntentFilter;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.os.PowerManager;
        import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public class Unlock_Service extends Service {
            ScreenBroadcastReceiver m_receiver;
            public String activityname;
            PowerManager pm;
            WakeLock wl;

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
                filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                m_receiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
                registerReceiver(m_receiver, filter);
                Log.d("Widgettool", "works");
            }

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                start();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SERVICE ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                return START_STICKY;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                stop();
                unregisterReceiver(m_receiver);
            }

            @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
            public void start() {
                try {

                    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, ".SensorActivity");
                    wl.acquire();
                    KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    lock.disableKeyguard();
                    // new TabActivityPacs().service();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            public void stop() {

                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this
                        .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                        + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
                activityname = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                componentInfo.getPackageName();

            }

            private class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                        Log.d("ON SCREEN ON", "might hang here");
                        // start();
                        stop();

                    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                        start();
                        Log.d("SCREEN OFF", "might hang here");
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

                return null;
            }

        }


    in your question... you have to use broadcast receiver in all activity then only you receive your corresponding information using service..
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suppose you do all what I'm trying. Actually I expect a more analyzing on How good this approach is (using broadcast on those activities which want to listen to the service) and What should be the WAY. My purpose is to update some UIs based on what is happening inside the service.